# Mail me when someone runs sudo

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sudo

I have added the below lines to `/etc/sudoers.d/my_sudoers`

```
Defaults    mail_always
Defaults    mailto="email@domain.com"
```

I get an email every time `sudo` is run

How can i modify this so I only receive emails when particular people run sudo (Everybody except 2 users)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is straightforward; `Defaults` can apply to specific users (and other limitations), and user aliases can be constructed with negated matches. Something along these lines:

```
User_Alias NoMail = goodboy, goodgirl
User_Alias MailUsers = ALL, !NoMail

Defaults           mailto="omgsudo@example.com"
Defaults:MailUsers mail_always
Defaults:NoMail    !mail_badpass
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work? Syntax error for both User_Alias commands

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail, specifically the exact line(s) you're trying to use along with the exact error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure on the syntax but wouldn't creating an if statement help
SUDO
if (name = NAME1, NAME2,)
{
do nothing
}
else
{
email
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only the two users exist in the `sudoers` file, the following will achieve what you want:

```
Defaults mailto="email@domain.com", mail_no_user
```

Otherwise, you'll probably need to resort to filtering your emails.

Comment: This didn't work. There must be another option without filtering emails.

Comment: I didn't realize that `mail_no_user` is on by default.