# User install package generates email

Tags: linux, security, linux-distributions

I wanted to know that is there any mechanism that when user install/uninstall any package by sudo. Its generates email and send it to the root's email address.
I am using centos 6.4 and usually install package through yum or by direct install(rpm).

Comment: Related, but does not exactly answer your question: [Mail me when someone runs sudo](http://superuser.com/q/581709/195224)

Comment: `sudo` does not install packages, it gives root access. What distribution are you using? I think what you are looking dor is an email when a user uses `apt-get install` or `rpm -i` or `pacman -s` or whatever package management system you are using.

Comment: @terdon yes you are right, can you help in that.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda hard to answer since you have not told us your distribution or which package manager you are using. There are various ways of doing this, one of which is making your package manager into a function. I will use `apt-get` as an example.

Rename the `apt-get` executable:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin/apt-get.bin
```

Make a little wrapper script that calls `apt-get` and then sends the email:

```
#!/bin/sh

./apt-get.bin "$@" && echo "User $SUDO_USER ran 'apt-get $@'" | 
  sendmail root@foo.com
```

Save the script above as `/usr/bin/apt-get` and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Now, each time a user successfully runs `apt-get` an email will be sent to `root@foo.com`.

This is not the most elegant of ways and it can easily be bypassed by a user calling `apt-get.bin` directly but it might serve for your needs. It will also not help if a user installs a package from source or uses `aptitude` or `dpkg` directly.